# NMOS bidirectional variable resistor: How to increase body diode barrier potential?

Tags: mosfet, nmos, body-diode, voltage-controlled-resistor

I want to use an NMOS as a variable input resistor to an inverting amplifier. The source is connected to virtual ground and the drain is connected to the input. I need to accomodate both positive and negative input drain voltages. I know that the NMOS requirement for triode operation is:

Vds< Vgs-Vth

This works for Vds>0....but i want the variable resistor to work even for Vds< 0. The NMOS still works as a voltage controlled resistor for negative drain voltages as long as the body diode isn't forward biased. So I need a large barrier potential to ensure that the diode doesn't conduct.

Right now my solution is to use multiple NMOS in series, but Is there a way to tweak the parameters and geometry of the NMOS to increase the diode barrier potential.

Comment: Are you trying to make a four-quadrant analog multiplier?

Comment: To actually answer the question, though, you can't change the body diode forward voltage by much. It's a function of the material the device is made of and how heavily-doped it is. Your best bet would be to use a silicon-carbide device, I suppose.

Comment: @feithry yes, I'm making a four quadrant multiplier. I only needed two quadrant for the rest of the circuit and I realized too late that I need four quadrant for the inputs. I'm making an analog ANN.

Comment: @feithry is there an equation for that or at least a reference material/guideline that you're aware of. I was thinking of using NMOS in series, so that the effective barrier potential would be the sum of them...maybe not sure if my reasoning is correct...

Comment: What about a BOSFET which you can make easily from 2 mosfets.

Comment: @Autistic what's a BOSFET?

Comment: My recommendation is to just get an AD633, really.

Comment: @ ElecNoob a BOSFET is a bidirectional device .They can be made from 2 mosfets where the gates and sources are tied together .In the pre google days you made things that could not be bought.

Comment: @Autistic i think I've seen that. Actually i've been thinking of using that or a transmission gate based design... but now I realized the transmission gate won't work so I'm thinking of using the BOSFET design or series NMOS: drain and source tied together, to increase the effective diode barrier potential.